# How to properly use geocoder from Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm developing a little web application with PHP, I have some address in my database (state, town, city) - "the state is always the same". But town and city vary.

Is there any way to force a preference search by location? For example, preference is always looking in the state of Delaware in USA.

So I can pass parameter something like this:

```
var address="{$city}, {$town}, Delaware";
```

The problem is that by doing this, I sometimes get results from other countries, is there any rule or algorithm to do what I want?

Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try appending " Delaware state" or " Delaware, USA".  There isn't any documented rule I know of, except that it attempts to match "postal addresses".

Per the documentation you can bias the search:

- by [viewport](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingViewports)
- by [region code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRegionCodes)